# OpenStack - KeyPair extension is sometimes unavailable

Tags: openstack, jclouds

I have a Java application that uses jclouds to launch new VMs. Lately, I've been getting a message from jclouds that says `Key Pairs are required by options, but the extension is not available!`. Interestingly (and very annoyingly), this is an intermittent thing. After some (varying) number of this error occurring, the application *will* succeed in its request and things will continue as normal.

If I request a list of extensions from the OpenStack environment ($Our_openstack_server/v2.1/$tenant_id/extensions) I do see `os-keypairs` there.

I do know that there were some upgrades done on OpenStack in  the last few months, but I don't know the scope of them.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this? I'm not very experienced with OpenStack and I'm not even sure how to continue debugging this!

(jclouds version is 1.9.2, OpenStack I think is 2.1)

Comment: Have you tried with jclouds 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT? There have been changes in OpenStack regarding the service catalog and how extensions are identified, and there are several patches that are only available in that version. Could you try it and post the feedback?

Comment: @IgnasiBarrera: I will look into that if nothing else seems to work, though it will easily take several days to roll that change out to where it's needed.